# Why Linux USB driver is transmitting anomalous value over the wire

Tags: c, linux, usb, driver

I am trying to understand a Linux driver for a USB Wi-Fi card by working through the source code and correlating it against a USB I/O hex dump collected using `usbmon`.  It's been going quite well but there is just one byte amongst thousands similar to it that seems to not correlate back to the source code.  Specifically, it is `Line 726` in `/drivers/staging/rtl8187se/r8180_rtl8225z2.c` (inside the Linux kernel source directory), which reads:

```
write_phy_ofdm(dev, 0x02, 0x62); mdelay(1);
```

I expect this line to result in 4 USB writes, namely with the third write payload being a `0x62`. Instead, the third write payload as reported by `usbmon` as being transmitted on the wire is`0x42` (not `0x62`).  To illustrate, here is the output from `usbmon` for this specific call (last column of every second line are the four payloads `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x42`, `0x82`):

```
ffff88011d317600 2404077138 S Co:2:004:0 s 40 05 ff7f 0000 0001 1 = 00
ffff88011d317600 2404077255 C Co:2:004:0 0 1 >
ffff88008d9a0600 2404077263 S Co:2:004:0 s 40 05 ff7e 0000 0001 1 = 00
ffff88008d9a0600 2404077380 C Co:2:004:0 0 1 >
ffff88011d317000 2404077388 S Co:2:004:0 s 40 05 ff7d 0000 0001 1 = 42
ffff88011d317000 2404077505 C Co:2:004:0 0 1 >
ffff88008d9a09c0 2404077513 S Co:2:004:0 s 40 05 ff7c 0000 0001 1 = 82
```

And below are the relevant function definitions:

**/drivers/staging/rtl8187se/r8180_core.c**

```
inline void write_phy_ofdm(struct net_device *dev, u8 adr, u32 data)
{
    data = data & 0xff;
    rtl8185_write_phy(dev, adr, data);
}
```

and

```
void rtl8185_write_phy(struct net_device *dev, u8 adr, u32 data) {  

    u32 phyw;

    adr |= 0x80;

    phyw = ((data<<8) | adr);

    /* Note that, we must write 0xff7c after 0x7d-0x7f to write BB register. */
    write_nic_byte(dev, 0x7f, ((phyw & 0xff000000) >> 24));
    write_nic_byte(dev, 0x7e, ((phyw & 0x00ff0000) >> 16));     
    write_nic_byte(dev, 0x7d, ((phyw & 0x0000ff00) >> 8));  
    write_nic_byte(dev, 0x7c, ((phyw & 0x000000ff)));

    /* this is ok to fail when we write AGC table. check for AGC table might
    be   * done by masking with 0x7f instead 
    of 0xff      */     /* if (phyr != (data&0xff)) 
    DMESGW("Phy write timeout %x %x %x", phyr, data, adr); */ 
}
```

and

```
void write_nic_byte(struct net_device *dev, int x, u8 y)
{
    writeb(y, (u8 *)dev->mem_start + x);
    udelay(20);
}
```

**/arch/xtensa/include/asm/io.h**

```
#define writeb(b, addr) (void)((*(volatile unsigned char *)(addr)) = (b))
```

Running through the call order, we start with `write_phy_ofdm(dev, 0x02, 0x62);`.  `write_phy_ofdm()` bitmasks `data` with the line `data = data & 0xff`, but `0x62` only occupies the lower byte anyway, so this doesn't change `data` at this point.  So `write_phy_ofdm` passes `0x62` onwards as the `data` argument to `rtl8185_write_phy()`. `rtl8185_write_phy` packs `data` and `adr` into the lower 16 bits of a u32 with the line `phyw = ((data << 8) | adr);`.  Note that `data` just shifts up 8-bits and because `adr` only occupies the lower 8-bits, OR'ing them doesn't modify the data portion of `phyw`.  The first two `write_nic_byte()` calls write the highest and second highest order bytes of `phyw` out to addresses `0xff7f` and `0xff7e` respectively.  Because the two highest order bytes of `phyw` are unoccupied, these result in two payloads of `0x00` as expected.  **The third `write_nic_byte()` call** is the one giving me grief.  I expect it to be simply bitshifting the data `0x62` back down to the lowest order byte and transmitting `0x62`.  Why it is transmitting `0x42` is what escapes me.

I must admit my understanding of the low level `writeb()` calls is merky, and perhaps this is where something unexpected is happening.  The only scent of any clue at all I could find is in a [diff from 2009](https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/11/10/492) which contains the line: `write_phy_ofdm(dev, 0x02, ((priv->card_type == USB) ? 0x42 : 0x62)); mdelay(1);` (note the value `0x42` rearing its ugly head).  I should note that I've even recompiled the kernel driver and added it into the running kernel with `rmmod rtl8187`/`insmod /path/to/my/compiled/.ko/file` just to be sure the source I had was consistent with the running driver (not newer or older), but I still get `0x42` instead of `0x62`.

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?  I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Did you consider asking on some kernel mailing list, or to the author of that precise file?

Comment: Are you sure that the message in the dump comes from exactly that place in the code? There seem to be other calls in that file which contain the 0x42.

Comment: @jpa bordering on certain.  I've traced the code up until that point successfully.  Furthermore, `0x62` doesn't show __anywhere__ in the write bytes in the `usbmon` hex dump.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that's the approach I'll take if I don't get any answers here.  I prefer the stackoverflow platform to mailing lists.

Comment: What about after that point, does the dump continue matching the lines 727 onwards?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I wasn't even looking in the right function definition, as there are two functions named `rtl8225z2_rf_init()` in different files. One is in `/drivers/staging/rtl8187se/r8180_rtl8225z2.c` (the version I was looking at which isn't being executed) and another in `/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8225.c` (the correct version I wasn't looking at, which is getting executed).  They're only subtly different, but one uses `write_phy_ofdm(dev, 0x02, 0x62);` while the other uses `write_phy_ofdm(dev, 0x02, 0x42);`.  And the lesson here is, don't rely on navigating to a function definition with tags in Emacs.